# How to add two numbers having same units in python

Tags: python, pandas, units-of-measurement

I have a pandas dataframe where one column has values in kiloTon as abbreviated 'kt'. Now when I perform groupby on Country column and year column and call aggregation function sum on Value column, it's not actually doing sum of values in value column.

[The dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84JJ8.png)

After performing above action, following is coming:

[After groupby n aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAB17.png)

However the expected output should be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp4yr.png)

Also the 'Value' column is of type object.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW if you want more tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you're going to do arithmetic, then you need to remove the units before you create the column.  pandas tries to figure out your data types, and when it sees `"1234 kt"`, that's a string.  So, make the data `1234` and put `kt` in the header.

Comment: Also, please make a [mre], meaning minimal example input data and desired output. You could probably just use one group from the groupby, or part of a group if it's large. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for your feedback in regards to my post. Shall make improvements in future.

Comment: @TimRoberts   Ahh! Alright. I wanted to know if there is any way to add values along with units (ofcourse same units) . So conclusion is we cant .
What you mean by putting kt in header ?

Comment: If the whole column is in kilotons, then make the header `'Value (kt)'` so there is no confusion.  If everything in the whole chart is kilotons, then maybe you can just add a note when you publish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using values with mixed numbers and letters then they will be strings of Pandas dtype **object**. You need to split of the numerical part, convert to an integer, put into a new column and then use groupby with sum or whatever. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Algeria', 'Algeria','Algeria','Angola', 'Angola'],
                   'Item': ['Wheat and products', 'Wheat and products','Wheat and products','Wheat and products','Wheat and products'],
                   'Year': [2004, 2004,2005,2004,2004],
                   'Value':['2731 kt', '2415 kt','2688 kt','2000 kt','1111 kt']
                   })

df['ValNum'] = df['Value'].str.extract(r"(\d+)").astype('int')

df2 = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['ValNum'].sum()

print(df2)
```

gives:

```
Country  Year
Algeria  2004    5146
         2005    2688
Angola   2004    3111
```